# News sources for python django

Tags: python, django, feed

I find myself continually sifting through the net to keep up with Python/Django/web development trends and news.  Does anyone recommend any good news sites that focus on web development or they Python community?  For example, what new Django modules are popular or interesting new jQuery plugins, etc.   Just curious to know how others keep their knowledge up to date.

Comment: http://code.google.com/query/#q=django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Django community aggregator](http://www.djangoproject.com/community/) is a great source of news and information about what people are doing with Django.

Comment: Thank you!  It's great that Django has such a strong community.

Answer (score 2):

Coder.io lists Django news too but Django's own community page is my primary source.

http://coder.io/tag/django

Answer (score 1):

[Django Dose](http://djangodose.com/) is great. They have a bit or erratic updates (but they're back to posting again), but when they do, they really pick up the most interesting developments, both in trunk and around the community. Also the [django sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/django/) is pretty good too, most things tend to come that way.

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll be adding these to my RSS feeds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I run a Tumblr blog called [Djangoed](http://djangoed.com) which picks out the best/interesting stories from various sources (including the community aggregator, Django Sites and Reddit amongst others).

Comment: Some very useful stuff on this blog.  I like the article about the Advanced Project Layout.